# how can one use os.listdir correctly on a network path?

Tags: python, windows

Following code :

```
def tema_get_file():
    logdir='T:\\'
    logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('tms_int_calls-')])
    return logfiles[-1]
```

This runs fine, but I am trying to get `logdir` to run with a direct path :
`\\servername\path\folder`
The drive T is a mapped drive. Originally, the files are on the C Drive.

As soon as I do that, I get the error message :

> WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
>   '\servername\path\folder/*.*'

I've tried :

`"\\servername\\path\\folder"` , `"\\servername\\path\\folder\\"`

and

`r"\\servername\path\folder"` , `r"\\servername\path\folder\"`

and

`"\\\\servername\\path\\folder"` , `"\\\\servername\\path\\folder\\"`

Comment: You cannot mix different types of slashes in windows path, like this: `T:\a/b`. So the problem is with `/.` trailer in the example error. Code however, does not show how path is assembled.

Comment: Just use forward slashes everywhere instead of backward slashes, and you'll be fine. The issue is that you mixed up forward and backward slashes if you take a closer look at the error.

Comment: @myaut : `logdir='\\servername\\path\\folder'`

Comment: or `logdir='\\servername\\path\\folder\\'`

Comment: @Games Brainiac : that was it. I am now using `logdir='//servername//path//folder//`

Comment: The path should be `'//server/path/folder'` or `r'\\server\path\folder'` or `'\\\\server\\path\\folder'`. A UNC path starts with 2 slashes, and path components are separated by 1 slash. Windows does allow repeating slash characters in the path, but that doesn't mean that you should. This has nothing to do with doubling each backslash in a string literal to escape it, i.e. `'\\\\'` is only 2 characters. Also, if you need a UNC path that exceeds 260 characters, use `u'\\\\?\\UNC\\server\\path\\folder'`. In this case, the path must be `unicode` and only use backslash.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, there's no problem with mixing slash and backslash for regular UNC paths. It's ugly, but you can use `r'\/server\path/folder'`. Windows normalizes slash to backlash when it converts the path to the NT kernel namespace, which only uses backslash as the path separator. The error was actually that there was only one initial slash, which is not a valid UNC path but actually relative to the current drive.

Answer (score 5):

For me both of the following work

```
os.listdir(r'\\server\folder')
os.listdir('\\\\server\\folder')
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir(myUNCpath)` cannot handle Windows UNC path correctly if the path string was not defined by a literal like `myUNCpath = "\\\\servername\\dir1\\dir2"` or using a raw string like `myUNCpath = "\\servername\dir1\dir2` even if the string variable is defined like that because listdir always doubles backslash from string variable.

But what the heck one could do if getting the UNC path string by reading it from a ini file or by any other config file?

There is no way to edit as a literal, nor is it possible to make it a raw string using this r character in front of.

As a work around I found out that, it is possible to split an overall UNC path string variable into it's single components (to get rid off this dammned backslash characters) and to recompose it using a literal definition and by this setting the backslash characters again. Then the string works well - incredibel but true!

Here is my function, to perform this work around. The string which is given back from the function will work as expected if the path in the file is defined as 
\servername\dir1\dir2  (without added backslash as a escape character)

```
...
myworkswellUNCPath = recomposeUNCpathstring(myUNCpath)

...

def recomposeUNCpathstring(UNCstring):

    pathstring1 = UNCstring.replace("\\\\", "").strip()
    pathComponents = pathstring1.split("\\")
    pathstring = "\\\\" + pathComponents[0] 

    for i in range(1, len(pathComponents)-1):
        pathstring = pathstring + "\\" + pathComponents[i]

    return pathstring
```

Cheers
Stefan

Comment: uups, sorry did a typing in my message

Comment: like myUNCpath = "\\servername\dir1\dir2" or using a raw string like myUNCpath = "\servername\dir1\dir2      should be     like myUNCpath = "\\\\servername\\dir1\\dir2" or using a raw string like myUNCpath = "\\servername\\dir1\\dir2

Comment: here is the correct sentence  ------>   like myUNCpath = "\\\\servername\\dir1\\dir2" or using a raw string like myUNCpath = r "\\servername\\dir1\\dir2

Comment: no no no, another mistake , here the ultimate right sentence  -----> like myUNCpath = "\\\\servername\\dir1\\dir2" or using a raw string like myUNCpath = r"\\servername\dir1\dir2  <---------   i am really not a friend of those backslashes! Excuse me!

Comment: :p instead of these comments you can edit your answer and make it right. Edit the answer and delete these comments.